# Regex in PowerShell to get user's name from Managedby property in Active Directory

Tags: regex, powershell

Can anyone help me with this. I need to derive a persons name from the "managedby" attribute in Active Directory which looks like this: CN=Bloggs\, Joe,OU=Users,OU=BlahBlah,DC=HalbHalb,DC=com. So I need to take everything out and be left with Bloggs, Joe

I really don't know enough about Regex but assume its going to involve using -replace in some way. I have tried following some examples on the web but I just get lost. I can remove all special characters using:

'CN=Bloggs\, Joe,OU=Users,OU=BlahBlah,DC=HalbHalb,DC=com' -replace '[\W]', '' but I have no idea how to clean that up further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name appears after `CN=` and continues to the first unescaped comma, you can use the following regex to do the trick: `.*?CN=(.*?),(?<!\\,).*` [(Demo)](https://regex101.com/r/P77fWg/1/)

This will match the entire string, and capture all text starting after `CN=` and ending before the first unescaped comma. It's easy to place this in a powershell command using a backreference:

```bsh
<your string> -replace ".*?CN=(.*?),(?<!\\,).*",'$1'
```

> Bloggs\, Joe

This will take the matched group and remove everything else. (Make sure the second part of the replace string is in single quotes!) If you want that backslash removed, you can do the following to get rid of it:

```bsh
<previous output> -replace "\\",""
```

Answer (score 0):

A little RegEx and a little string manipulation...

```
$String = 'CN=Bloggs\, Joe,OU=Users,OU=BlahBlah,DC=HalbHalb,DC=com'
(($String.SubString(3) -split "OU")[0].Replace('\','') -split ",$")[0]
```